# Firefox does not support JavaScript (form validation) but IE fully support

Tags: php, javascript, html

I developed a user input form in php used (php, html, javascript…). I wrote validate functions in JavaScript.
The form is working fine in internet explorer and validate all the fields, but when I open in Firefox then, the form and fields not validate like (drop down menu field) not validate, but why? I am new in web development and very much upset.
Please anybody help me to solve this problem.
I appreciated in advance.

Browsers details:
Internet explorer  8.0
Firefox 3.6

the code is here.

```
function validateFormOnSubmit2(theForm) {
var reason = "";

  reason += validateState(theForm.state);        
  if (reason != "") {
    alert("State field need correction:\n" + reason);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function validateState(fld) {
    var error = "";


   if (fld.value == "") {
        error = "Please Select State.\n";
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } 
    return error;
}
```

### call function.

```
form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" 
      action="state_results.php" 
      onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit2(this)">
```

---

this code is validate in IE, and work fine, But not validate in FF,
if user not select "STATE" it goes ahead and not check/validate.

Comment: You'll need to provide the code, or modified examples of the code.

Comment: You most likely used some outdated IE-only approach to access the form elements, which is sadly what many online tutorials show. As Fosco said, please add a code sample and any error messages you receive to your question.

Comment: i added my small piece of code. There is no error message, just not validate form's fields like "drop down menu", if user not select any item from drop down menu, it does not validate and goes ahead. and do not show results, because the field is empty. but IE validate and show alert, if user do not select any item from drop down menu.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided any code, so we can only guess. The odds are that you are using a Doctype that fails to trigger standards mode (or no Doctype at all) and that you are using proprietary Microsoft DOM properties instead of standard ones.