# Firefox does not support JavaScript (form validation) but IE fully support

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```
function validateFormOnSubmit2(theForm) {
var reason = "";

  reason += validateState(theForm.state);        
  if (reason != "") {
    alert("State field need correction:\n" + reason);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function validateState(fld) {
    var error = "";


   if (fld.value == "") {
        error = "Please Select State.\n";
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } 
    return error;
}
```

call this function when i click on submit button.

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="state_results.php" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit2(this)">



<select name="state" id="state">
                  <option selected="selected">Select State...</option>
                  <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                  <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                  <option value="California">California</option>
                  <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                  <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                  <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                  <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                  <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                  <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                  <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                  <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                  <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                  <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                  <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                  <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                  <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                  <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                  <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                  <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                  <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                  <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                  <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                  <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                  <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                  <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                  <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                  <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                  <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                  <option value="New York">New York</option>
                  <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                  <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                  <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                  <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                  <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                  <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                  <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                  <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                  <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                  <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                  <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                  <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                  <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                  <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                  <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                  <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                  <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                  <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                </select>

<input name="submit2" type="submit" id="submit2" value="Search!" />
```

Comment: You mean "My code only works in IE".

Comment: "Yes", not in Firefox. i have firefox 3.6, IE 8.0

Comment: I like it how you're answering to comments and ignored my solution in the meantime...

Comment: Dear  galambalazs
Bundle of thanks for help, your code is great and very easy, but it is still not working.
Note: 
There is a point, all the other fields are validate but only “drop down menu” not validate in firefox.
But in IE everything is perfect and validate.
Please help me, I appreciated you.
Thank.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox does not support JavaScript (form validation) but IE fully support.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197756/firefox-does-not-support-javascript-form-validation-but-ie-fully-support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that `<select>` elements do not have a `value` attribute in all browsers.

You can, however, ask the `<select>` element for its selected index, and for its options.  try something like this:

```
function validateState(fld) {
    var error = "";
    var value = fld.options[fld.selectedIndex].value;

   if (value == "") {
        error = "Please Select State.\n";
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } 
    return error;
}
```

In addition, you should be sure that the first option "Select State..." has a `value` attribute, and set it to the empty string:

```
<option selected="selected" value="">Select State...</option>
```

Comment: Hi! pkaeding,
Bundle of thanks for help, I applied your code below, that was awesome, now it is working fine and validating on both browsers IE and FF.

<option selected="selected" value="">Select State...</option>

  
Everyone ones again thanks for help and solved my problem, I was very upset.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help.  If you feel that my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as the 'accepted' answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.  You can also upvote any answers you thought were helpful by clicking the triangle pointing up next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateFormOnSubmit2(theForm) {
  var reason = validateState(theForm.state);
  if (reason) { // if there is a reason
    alert("State field need correction:\n" + reason);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validateState(field) {
   if (field.value == "") {
       field.style.background = 'Yellow';
       return "Please Select State.\n";
   }
   // returns undefined by default
   // means: there is no reason
   // (the reason is not defined)
}
```

---

> ### UPDATED

As for your updated question. The only thing you need to do in order to get it work for dropdowns, is to set the default `"Select State..."` option's value to '' (empty string).

**HTML**

```
<option selected="selected" value="">Select State...</option>
```

The javascript code stays the same.

Comment: Dear  galambalazs
Bundle of thanks for help, your code is great and very easy, but it is still not working.
Note: 
There is a point, all the other fields are validate but only “drop down menu” not validate in firefox.
But in IE everything is perfect and validate.
Please help me, I appreciated you.
Thank.

Comment: show the html please (paste it to http://jsbin.com/, then create public link, and then post it here)

Comment: can you specify how do you want to validate a drop down exactly? Because a drop down is always got an element selected by default...

Comment: My guess is he wants to make sure the first option "Select State..." is not still selected when the user tries to submit.

Comment: @pkaeding I've updated the answer, to fit your needs. Have fun! :)

Comment: Hi! pkaeding, 
Bundle of thanks for help, I applied your code below, that was awesome, now it is working fine and validating on both browsers IE and FF.
<option selected="selected" value="">Select State...</option>
  
@galambalazs and Everyone ones again thanks for help and solved my problem, I was very upset.